# Multi File Diff in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is there a way I can show a diff/compare window like the commit window but not based on the most recent commit, rather an older commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 4.6.2 there is a little timer icon in between the two text editors when in the version editor. This allows you to go back to previous revisions.

[image: Here is the timeline]

See the screenshot.